# Set Visual Studio source control provider in a script

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, team-explorer

Visual Studio 2017 has a setting for the source control provider (Team Foundation Server, Git, ...). Does anybody know how to set this setting from a script or where Visual Studio does store this setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source control provider can be set using `vsregedit.exe`.

To set Git as the source control provider from a PowerShell script:

```
$vsWherePath = Join-Path ${env:ProgramFiles(x86)} "Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe"
$vsVersion = "[15.0,16.0)"
$installPath = &$vsWherePath -all -latest -version $vsVersion -property installationPath
$vsregedit = Join-Path $installPath 'Common7\IDE\vsregedit.exe'


&$vsregedit set "$installPath" HKCU CurrentSourceControlProvider `"`" string "{11B8E6D7-C08B-4385-B321-321078CDD1F8}"
```

Comment: Would you be able to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63046302/how-to-change-the-visual-studio-build-output-verbosity-through-scripting ?