# How to change the Visual Studio build output verbosity through scripting?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Note, that I am not talking about msbuild output verbosity, but about devenv - the IDE:

[image]

It uses registry for that. However, in VS 2015 the registry keys were clear and the following simple script did the job:

```
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory)][ValidateRange(1,4)][int]$level
)

$path = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\General"

Set-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name MSBuildLogFileVerbosity -Value $level -Type DWord
Set-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name MSBuildLoggerVerbosity -Value $level -Type DWord
```

In VS 2019 the registry path contains a guid and the key itself looks kind of weird. So, this is my opportunity to ask - is there a better way to do it programmatically?

**EDIT 1**

So I read the posts referenced in the comments and came up with the following  function:

```
$VSBuildVerbosityLevels = @(
    'quiet',
    'minimal',
    'normal',
    'detailed',
    'diagnostic'
)
function Get-VSBuildVerbosity
{
    [CmdLetBinding()]
    param()
    $vsWhere = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe"
    $installPath = & $vsWhere -latest -property installationPath
    $vsregedit = "$installPath\Common7\IDE\vsregedit.exe"

    $cmd = "& `"$vsregedit`" read local HKCU General MSBuildLoggerVerbosity dword"
    Write-Verbose $cmd
    $Level = (Invoke-Expression $cmd).Substring('Name: MSBuildLoggerVerbosity, Value: '.Length)
    $VSBuildVerbosityLevels[$Level]
}
```

Please, observe:

```
C:\> Get-VSBuildVerbosity -Verbose
VERBOSE: & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\vsregedit.exe" read local HKCU General MSBuildLoggerVerbosity dword
minimal
C:\>
```

But it does not seem to return the right result:
[image]

The VS version is supposed to be correct:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019
Version 16.6.3
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.6.3+30225.117
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.03190

Installed Version: Enterprise

...
```

According to procmon, changing the value in the IDE affects the following registry key:

```
\REGISTRY\A\{a7e8587a-40a4-a5b0-0119-e9050f63198a}\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_44c67ac6\General\MSBuildLoggerVerbosity
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT 2**

Running procmon reveals that VS IDE and vsregedit touch different registry keys:
[image]

- VS IDE - `\REGISTRY\A\{a7e8587a-40a4-a5b0-0119-e9050f63198a}\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_44c67ac6\General\MSBuildLoggerVerbosity`
- vsregedit - `\REGISTRY\A\{d8a7e391-9143-745b-e649-9339d4390cfe}\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_44c67ac6\General\MSBuildLoggerVerbosity`

Now what?

**EDIT 3**

Here is my code to set it:

```
$VSBuildVerbosityLevelMap = @{ }
$VSBuildVerbosityLevels | ForEach-Object { $i = 0 } {
    $VSBuildVerbosityLevelMap[$_] = $i
    ++$i
}
function Set-VSBuildVerbosity(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][ValidateSet('quiet', 'minimal', 'normal', 'detailed', 'diagnostic')]$Level
)
{
    $vsWhere = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe"
    $installPath = & $vsWhere -latest -property installationPath
    $vsregedit = "$installPath\Common7\IDE\vsregedit.exe"

    $cmd = "& `"$vsregedit`" set local HKCU General MSBuildLoggerVerbosity dword $($VSBuildVerbosityLevelMap[$Level])"
    Write-Verbose $cmd
    $null = Invoke-Expression $cmd
}
```

**EDIT 4**

This is really curious. I was using my function to set the verbosity and it appears to be working, BUT the Visual Studio dialog does not seem to recognize it! Observe:
[image]

The build outputs diagnostics, but the Build And Run property sheet tells us the build output verbosity is Minimal!

That is what sets me aback - the Powershell code appears to set the verbosity correctly, but the Build and Run options dialog seems to report a different value!

Comment: See https://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2017/06/29/changing-visual-studio-2017-private-registry-settings/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894153/set-visual-studio-source-control-provider-in-a-script

Comment: Looks promising. Will have to look into it.

Comment: Please, see **EDIT 1**.

Comment: and now also **EDIT 2**

Comment: A\{guids} could be different as they just temporary mount points. 16.0_44c67ac6 are the same and this identifies an installed VS instance.

Comment: Works correctly for me: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\VsRegEdit.exe" read local HKCU General MSBuildLoggerVerbosity dword
Name: MSBuildLoggerVerbosity, Value: 4

Comment: Make sure VS is closed and closed all its internal processes.

Comment: I did. The VS IDE does not seem to pick the change when I restart it and check the verbosity there. Are you saying that when you change it in IDE and close VS, the console output matches what you set in the IDE? It does not match for me.

Comment: Yes, when I change it in IDE and close VS, the console output matches what I set in the IDE.

Comment: That is truly mysterious to me. It does not work like this for me.

Comment: @SergeyVlasov - Please, see **EDIT 4**. I cannot explain it, but it is good enough for me. Please, arrange your comments as an answer so I could credit you.

Comment: Thank you, but credit for PowerShell vsregedit code should go to Pascal Berger.

Comment: Already did. I would like my question to have an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio includes a vsregedit.exe utility that you can use to change Visual Studio settings:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\VsRegEdit.exe" set local HKCU General MSBuildLoggerVerbosity dword 4
```