# Visual Studio settings for all users

Tags: visual-studio, settings, global

I have a lab of thin clients running Windows. Each client logs on as a new user so when I set up the initial image, the settings that I select (It asks whether I want to create an account and the background I want to use, light or dark). Are there registry entries I can set so that any user will have those choices already selected and a user of the client won't have to choose those settings every time they start Visual Studio?

Comment: What Visual Studio version are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio Enterprise 2019

Comment: You can try vsregedit.exe https://stackoverflow.com/a/63387690/84507

Comment: I will try it out. Thanks