# Why does the setting "MSBuild project build output verbosity" have no effect?

Tags: c++, msbuild, visual-studio-2022

I am having trouble finding relevant messages in a myriad of MSBuild output. It seems like a problem with my Visual Studio configuration: the build output verbosity behaves as if it is set to "Detailed", independent from what I have set in *Tools → Options → Projects and Solutions → Build and Run → MSBuild project build output verbosity*.

The issue is reproducable with a default C++ console application project:

[image]

The screenshot shows the application, the ouput verbosity settings and the unexpected output in the "Output" window.

I came across this problem in another project that has a significantly longer build time. When I open the settings window while the project is building, I can see that the setting has reset to "Detailed"

**Do you have any idea why the setting does not have an effect or why it is overridden?**

As written, the problem is project-independent and seems like an issue with my configuration. I already tried deleting the settings in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\...` and `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\...`
but Visual Studio manages to restore the settings from some history:

[image]

Comment: What is the *Output Verbosity* drop-down in the Output window show? I can't reproduce the issue in VS2022 v17.3.5 but I did see an issue in an earlier version of VS where the *Tools → Options → Projects and Solutions → Build and Run → MSBuild project build output verbosity* setting and the *Output Verbosity* setting (which are supposed to be the same setting) were showing different values.

Comment: @JonathanDodds thanks for your comment! Could you please give me a hint where to find said *Output Verbosity* drop-down? I tried right-clicking in the output window and searching in the settings but I can only find *MSBuild project build ouput verbosity*.

Comment: Output windows showing Output Verbosity drop-down

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hXAK.png

Comment: @JonathanDodds thanks for showing! Funnily enough, this option is missing in my output window. https://imgur.com/a/EQI8xPd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was solved with an update to Visual Studio 22 Version 17.5.0

[Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes)

[Fixed Bugs](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio?q=%5BFixed+In%3A+Visual+Studio+2022+version+17.5%5D)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the same account to sign in vs on different computers? Maybe this cause the problem.

You can try to reset all settings under Tools > Import and Export Settings and try it again.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip how to reset the settings. I tried resetting to "General" and "Visual C++"  but I do still get the detailed output. I only use this single instance of VS on my work laptop.

Comment: Maybe you can try this: cancel the option "Synchronize Visual Studio settings across devices and installs on this machine(enabling this way overwrite local settings)" in Tools>Options>Environment>Accounts or remove your account from Help>Register Visual Studio and try again. Tell me if it works or not.

Comment: I tried disabling the option "Synchronize Visual Studio settings across devices and installs on this machine(enabling this way overwrite local settings)" but still get the detailed MSBuild output.

Comment: Remove your account from Help>Register Visual Studio also doesn't work? If it doesn't work, last suggestion is to reinstall vs in visual studio installer.

Comment: No, removing my account unfortunately also did not help. I will try reinstalling and give you an update when it is done.

Comment: Jingmiao Xu-MSFT : reinstalling unfortunately also did not fix it.

Comment: Did the error window "the automatically saved settings file cannot be found" shows every time when you open visual studio?

Comment: Are there any errors when closing vs? Maybe some settings on your computer prevent you from modifying the CurrentSettings.vssettings file when close Visual Studio. You can turn off your antivirus software and try again.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63046302/how-to-change-the-visual-studio-build-output-verbosity-through-scripting) use vsregedit.exe to change visual studio settings. Hope it can help.

Comment: The error window only appears the first time after deleting the settings. I do not get any errors when closing VS. Trying with disabled antivirus unfortunately is not possible with our companies domain settings. I searched the registry for "MSBuildLoggerVerbosity" and could not find it, so I assume it was not set yet. I did set it with the vsregedit.exe tool but it did not show an effect. Nevertheless I will look into that more.

Thank you for all the suggestions / hints!

Comment: If you find a solution you can add an answer about this problem. Good luck.